# Converting generic objects to typed objects

Tags: c#, generics, servicestack

```
public class Generic
{
   public object AnonObject {get;set;}
   public string ObjectType {get;set;}
}


public class TypedObject
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way of converting the anonymous property `AnonObject` within class [Generic] to [TypedObject] using `ServiceStack serialization` or other library.

e.g. Ideally, I am looking for a method

```
TypedObject typed = generic.AnonObject.ConvertTo<TypedObject>();
```

or

```
TypedObject typed = generic.AnonObject As TypedOject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use still use ServiceStack's [built-in Auto Mapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) to convert between anonymous and typed objects but they still must have the same shape, e.g:

```
public class Poco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

var anon = new { Id = 1, Title = "Foo" };
var dto = anon.ConvertTo<Poco>();

dto.PrintDump();
```

Which prints the populated DTO:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Title: Foo
}
```

The `ToObjectDictionary` and `FromObjectDictionary` extension methods are also useful in trying to convert loosely-typed data structures into a Typed POCO's, e.g:

```
var dto = new User
{
    FirstName = "First",
    LastName = "Last",
    Car = new Car { Age = 10, Name = "ZCar" },
};

Dictionary<string,object> map = dtoUser.ToObjectDictionary();

User user = (User)map.FromObjectDictionary(typeof(User));
```

If the above options aren't enough another potential solution is to serialize/deserialize the object as JSON, e.g:

```
var json = new { Id = 1, Title = "Foo" }.ToJson();
var dto = json.FromJson<Poco>();
```

Comment: Thank you, the FromObjectDictionary and ToObjectDictionary worked for me. Not sure why the others did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ServiceStack's [built-in Auto-Mapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) methods?

```
TypedObject typed = generic.AnonObject.To<TypedObject>();

TypedObject typed = generic.AnonObject.TranslateTo<TypedObject>();

TypedObject typed = generic.AnonObject.ConvertTo<TypedObject>();

TypedObject typed  = new TypedObject();
typed.PopulateWith(generic.AnonObject);
```